# I am getting error "java.sql.SQLException: After end of result set" while trying to access this returned resultSetCustomer.from other methode

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

```
 public ResultSet getAllCustomer() throws SQLException{
  //List L = new ArrayList();
    try {
           stm = con.prepareStatement("select * from customer");
     
      resultSetSubject = stm.executeQuery();
        while (resultSetCustomer.next()) {
            
            //L.add(resultSetCustomer);
            
         resultSetCustomer.getInt(1);
             resultSetCustomer.getString(2);
             
           
            
            //System.out.println(resultSetCustomer.getInt("id")+" "+resultSetCustomer.getString("name"));
           
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println(e);
    } 
     
       
  return resultSetCustomer;
   
}
```

Let me brief, I am fetching all record from the customer table  and returning as resultset. I am accessing returned resultset as

ResultSet rs = T.getAllCustomer();

```
          System.out.println(rs.getInt("id")+" "+rs.getString("name"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code needed little amendment

1 > Ensure resultset variable you use are same as defined (one place its different in your code).

2> use only

```
public ResultSet getAllCustomer() throws SQLException{
try {
       stm = con.prepareStatement("select * from customer");
 
  resultSetCustomer = stm.executeQuery();
   
} catch (Exception e) {
     System.out.println(e);
}  
  return resultSetCustomer;
```

}

3> Close your connection/resultset/statement in separate method otherwise you will get error. you can use as below

```
public void close() throws SQLException{
     
     if (resultSetCustomer != null) {
         resultSetCustomer .close();
     }
     if (stm !=null) {
         stm.close();
     }
 }
```

4> use resultset(your resultset instance).next() while accessing

Comment: Thankx its worked .. just I need to use next() in 2 places while calling

Answer (score 3):

There are several issues in your code:

1. You are obtaining a `ResultSet` object, looping over all of the rows in it, getting the column values, and then returning this `ResultSet` object. By the time it is returned to the caller, it has already been consumed by the loop that processed the rows (this is the cause of the error in your question).
2. Don't return the `ResultSet` object, instead create a `Customer` entity class that maps to the data in the DB, and return an instance of `Customer`. Returning a `ResultSet` object is really bad as it doesn't give control over how the object is closed, nor does it make your code object-oriented.
3. You don't need to create a prepared statement if you don't have a parameterized query.
4. The `Statement` (and `ResultSet`) must be `close`d after done. You should wrap the code that processes the whole result in a [`try-with-resources` statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Comment: Thanks for your hand..   please note, My program requires to return resulset not any instance of a customer. I did close statement and resultset, however its shows error hence trying other process to test as pasted avobe. Solution needs to be how i can return resultset. Please any input on this, how i can do this ?

Comment: @NEHASURDESHAI the main issue in your code is that you are processing the result set in the method itself (the `while (resultSetCustomer.next()) {` loop).  That part should be done by the caller of the method, not the method itself. Processing the result set in the method is consuming the result set, hence causing the error when the caller tries to use it.